# RubyMotion: Find each character entry in UITextField

Tags: ios, delegates, rubymotion

I am new to RubyMotion for iOS app, but I coded using Objective C.

My requirement is to get the delegate method which should be called for every char type in UITextField.

Objective C:  I used "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" for finding the user character entry.

Can you anyone suggest me how to implement this function in RubyMotion for tracking character type in UITextField

Thank you.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you create the text field, make sure you set the delegate to the same View Controller class it's in:

```
textField = UITextField.alloc.initWithFrame([[10,200],[300,40]])
textField.delegate = self
```

Then add this method to that class:

```
def textField(textField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range, replacementString:string)
  # return true or false based on whether you want to allow the replacement
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the BubbleWrap syntax:

```
textField.when(UIControlEventEditingChanged) do
  # something
end
```